# youtube のユーザーごとの再生回数を取得したいです。

Tags: youtube-data-api

youtube　api などを使用してユーザーごとの再生回数を取得したいと思っています。

youtube　apiのページを見ましたがサンプルコードや取得できる項目の中にユーザーごとの再生回数が見つかりませんでした。　取得できる方法がございましたら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

ユーザではなくチャンネルごとの再生回数であれば以下のURLで取得できそうです。

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings,statistics,snippet&id={チャンネルID}&key={APIキー}
```

リファレンスは以下です。
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels?hl=ja

Comment: 情報提供頂きありがとうございます！